# Angular service slugify scopes

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am slugify function running smoothly.

What bothers me is having to repeat the function code in all controllers.

There is the possibility of converting into a service, or otherwise I write only once this function?

Today use of this form:

```
<md-input-container class="md-accent">
    <label >Digite o título do Produto</label>
    <input ng-model="product.title" ng-change="slugify(product.title)">
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container class="md-accent">
    <label>Link permanente</label>
    <input ng-model="product.slug" disabled>
</md-input-container>
```

my slugify function:

```
$scope.slugify = function(slug){
    var makeString = function(object) {
        if (object === null) {
            return '';
        }
        return '' + object;
    };

    var from  = 'ąàáäâãåæăćčĉęèéëêĝĥìíïîĵłľńňòóöőôõðøśșšŝťțŭùúüűûñÿýçżźž',
        to    = 'aaaaaaaaaccceeeeeghiiiijllnnoooooooossssttuuuuuunyyczzz',
        regex = new RegExp('[' + from + ']', 'g');

    slug = makeString(slug).toString().toLowerCase().replace(regex, function (c){
        var index = from.indexOf(c);
        return to.charAt(index) || '-';
    }).replace(/[^\w\-\s]+/g, '').trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/\-\-+/g, '-');

    $scope.product.slug = slug;
};
```

**SOLUTION HERE! FACTORY:**

```
.factory('slugify', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.generate = function(slug){
        var makeString = function(object) {
            if (object === null) {
                return '';
            }
            return '' + object;
        };

        var from  = 'ąàáäâãåæăćčĉęèéëêĝĥìíïîĵłľńňòóöőôõðøśșšŝťțŭùúüűûñÿýçżźž',
            to    = 'aaaaaaaaaccceeeeeghiiiijllnnoooooooossssttuuuuuunyyczzz',
            regex = new RegExp('[' + from + ']', 'g');

        slug = makeString(slug).toString().toLowerCase().replace(regex, function (c){
            var index = from.indexOf(c);
            return to.charAt(index) || '-';
        }).replace(/[^\w\-\s]+/g, '').trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/\-\-+/g, '-');
        return slug;
    };
    return self;
});
```

And in controllers:

```
$scope.slugIt = function(title){
    $scope.product.slug = slugify.generate(title);
};
```

And in views:

```
<input ng-model="product.title" ng-change="slugIt(product.title)">
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact requirement. But, you can write a service something like this

```
angular.module('app').service('slugService',
    function () {
        function serviceInstance() {
            var services = {
                slugify: slugify,
                slug: slug
            };

            var slug = null;

            function slugify(slug) {
                var makeString = function (object) {
                    if (object === null) {
                        return '';
                    }
                    return '' + object;
                };

                var from = 'ąàáäâãåæăćčĉęèéëêĝĥìíïîĵłľńňòóöőôõðøśșšŝťțŭùúüűûñÿýçżźž',
                    to = 'aaaaaaaaaccceeeeeghiiiijllnnoooooooossssttuuuuuunyyczzz',
                    regex = new RegExp('[' + from + ']', 'g');

                this.slug = makeString(slug).toString().toLowerCase().replace(regex, function (c) {
                        var index = from.indexOf(c);
                        return to.charAt(index) || '-';
                    })
                    .replace(/[^\w\-\s]+/g, '')
                    .trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-')
                    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-');

            }

            return services;
        }

        return new serviceInstance();
    }
);

//inject the service in your controller
angular.module('app').controller('urController', function(slugService){


}

and use it in your view

ng-change(slugService.slugify(product.title))

ng-model(slugService.slug)  //probably need to use ng-init as well
```

//assuming the service is used once per page

Comment: Hi, thax fast response, but return this error: Error: slug is not defined

Comment: Edited, missed to add slug = null after services.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a directive, that uses the service to generate a slug.

```
.factory('slugger', function slugger() {
    return {
        generateSlug: generateSlug
    };

    function generateSlug(input) {
        var from = 'ąàáäâãåæăćčĉęèéëêĝĥìíïîĵłľńňòóöőôõðøśșšŝťțŭùúüűûñÿýçżźž';
        var to = 'aaaaaaaaaccceeeeeghiiiijllnnoooooooossssttuuuuuunyyczzz';
        var regex = new RegExp('[' + from + ']', 'g');

        input = makeString(input).toString().toLowerCase().replace(regex, function (c) {
            var index = from.indexOf(c);
            return to.charAt(index) || '-';
        }).replace(/[^\w\-\s]+/g, '').trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/\-\-+/g, '-');

        return input;
    }

    function makeString(object) {
        if (object === null) {
            return '';
        }

        return '' + object;
    }
})

.directive('slugInput', function (slugger) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            iElement.on('input', function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(slugger.generateSlug(iElement.val()));
                ngModelCtrl.$render();
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                iElement.off('input');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Usage:

Anywhere in your app,

```
<input ng-model="product.title" slug-input>
```

Comment: Good idea, but .. in my case does not work, I have two inputs, the first is the title and the second the permalink, what I do is when I type in the title he has me generates the permalink field with slugify the field permalink is inactive.